# Embed credentials for webclient in C# Console Application app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, app-config, networkcredentials

Currently I'm using a login method like this to login, but I want to embed this into the app.config file for safe keeping...

Currently it looks like this.

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();  
c.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UN", "PW", "server");
```

How can I embed this into the app.config file???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="NetworkCredentialUserName" value="UN" />
  <add key="NetworkCredentialPassword" value="PW" />
</appSettings>
```

Then

```
var networkCredentialUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetworkCredentialUserName"];
var networkCredentialPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetworkCredentialPassword"];
c.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(networkCredentialUserName, networkCredentialPassword , "server");
```

This however does not make them secure. If the network credential username & password are sensitive, I would consider encrypting the app.config appSettings section using something like PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider (a nuget package).

Comment: Okay so those "Key"s are just rando names you made up? Will test!

Comment: They keys are not random, but you can name them whatever you want. Just keep in mind you can't have more than 1 appSetting with the same key.

Comment: In addition to this answer, you may want to encrypt password with `ProtectedData` class. See this MSDN article for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx

Comment: Worked like a charm, and thanks for the extra information Anton! Marking as answer, upvotes for all.