# Why does creating contact forms require a password?

Tags: c#, asp.net, contact-form

So Im looking at having a contact form on my website where a person can type a message and send it, with the mesage going to my inbox.

But every time I see them online Ill see this:

```
 System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourEmail@gmail.com", "YourPassword");
```

Why do I need to provide my password? When you send someone a regular email, you dont need THEIR password.

I also have security concerns. Ok, it's in a .cs file, but still, I dont like seeing my password in plain text there.

Also, what about if its for a big company? Does ebay have their password in plain text? It's something I doubt. How do other people do it?

Comment: before you downvote my question can you at least tell me why you downvoted? If its a stupid question then tell me but the answer isnt obvious to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely don't want the users password.

But for your contact form to be able to send a mail it needs to be send by a valid email client. Say for example you want to use the gmail server for your mail, you need to provide your credentials for it.

As for the second part of your question, please don't store these plain text in code. You can easily acces those from app.config / web.config

(for example see: [Embed credentials for webclient in C# Console Application app.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574657/embed-credentials-for-webclient-in-c-sharp-console-application-app-config))

Comment: Thank you. Im marking yours as the answer because you answered it fastest and showed me how to move the text to web.config

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have your own SMTP relay and your own credentials.

So when setting up the mailer on your side, you need to specify a reply to email address.

Below is a working example of how do it

```
var m = new MailMessage { Subject = txtSubject.Text, IsBodyHtml = true, Body = emailOpeningLine + txtMessage.Text };

            try
            {
                m.To.Add(new MailAddress("to");
                m.From = new MailAddress("senders email address");
                m.ReplyToList.Add("senders email address");
                foreach (var attachment in Attactments)
                {
                    m.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment));
                }
                client.Send(m);
                m.To.Clear();
                m.Attachments.Clear();

            }

            catch (SmtpException esException)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }
```

Re your other questions,  you can keep the passwords in a database, but remember to encrypt them.

Comment: thank you. I will try your example tomorrow because im giving it a break for now. I'll let you know if it worked

Comment: No worries :) m